# Problems setting JARs to classpath in Pl/Java

Tags: java, postgresql, pljava

I seem to be having a problem setting multiple JAR files to the classpath for Pl/Java.

For each JAR file, I have installed the JARs, using `install_jar`.

But what I now need to do is add each JAR to the classpath, I try the following:

```
SELECT sqlj.set_classpath('public', 'lib1; lib2');
```

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.tada.se/index.php?title=Set_classpath) it mentions the following:

```
> Usage: set_classpath
>
> SELECT sqlj.set_classpath(<schema>, <classpath>);
>
> Parameter    Description:
>  -schema:    The name of the schema. 
>  -classpath: The colon separated list of jar names.
```

Although the above does **not** work, returning the following error:

```
ERROR:  java.sql.SQLException: No such jar: lib1; lib2
```

Can anyone help to see how I can install more than one JAR to the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key appears to be "colon separated".  *nix uses colons (e.g. jar1:jar2) and Windows uses semi-colons (e.g. jar1;jar2).  Make sure you're using the right one for your OS.